I cannot get Ubuntu 24.04 to install
I have experience with Linux (Mint and Ubuntu), so I am not a total newb. I've been able to get Ubuntu 24.04 to install successfully on an old Microsoft Surface Pro tablet where it is the only OS on the device. I've been able to install Ubuntu 22.04 to install a few years ago in a dual boot manner, but something is hanging up my installation attempts this time.
In my first attempts last week, I was able to boot into the Ubuntu installer, connect to my wifi, choose my setup options (choosing dual boot and create a 120-150GB partition on my NVMe drive which contains my Windows OS). The installation was flawless up to that point until I got the "Oh no! Something went wrong" message. I did this a few times. On two occasions I shared bug reports on the default forum (answers.launchpad.net). I've gotten help there, but I still haven't been able resolve this problem.
I got hung up for a while trying to verify my ISO. For some reason, I couldn't get the command to verify my checksum even though I saved the ISO, the SHA256SUMS, and the SHA256SUMS.gpg in my Downloads folder with nothing else in there. I did a great deal of troubleshooting and it got nowhere.
No matter what I do when I run the command: gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS I get the response:
gpg: can't open 'SHA256SUMS.gpg': No such file or directory    
gpg: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory  

I gave up today and just trusted that by torrenting my ISO from Ubuntu and having read that balenaEtcher does some verification. I went ahead and attempted to install it again. That was about an hour ago. I will now paste in the notes I took about that attempt. Unfortunately, something went wrong in a new way.
Here's the short version. I booted into the Ubuntu installer with no problems. I went through all the steps with no problems until it came to the step where I choose between dual boot or overwriting everything and installing Ubuntu as my only OS or choosing an advanced setup. I was only offered a manual setup with no dual boot option.
Here is a detailed account of the attempt.
I started by opening the Disk Management tool to verify the state of my target drive. Windows Disk Management tool showed my 1TB M2 drive consists of two partitions: 100MB for EFI (Healthy) and a 953.75GB NTFS partition for my Windows C: (Healthy). I thought there was a recovery partition on that disk somewhere, so I used DISKPART in the Windows PowerShell and found that yes, there is a 16MB partition that I assume is the Windows recovery partition.
I downloaded the ISO again using Ubuntu's torrent site and Torrent Downloader HD. I used balenaEtcher to flash it to a USB drive. I set the USB as the boot priority in the BIOS and restarted my PC with the USB drive plugged in. The Ubuntu OS came up without issue and I chose my language, keyboard, and connected to my wifi.
When it asked how I wanted to install Ubuntu I chose interactive installation. I then chose to include everything in an extended selection (as opposed to a default selection). I chose to install both the third-party software and additional media formats. When it asked how I wanted to install Ubuntu, there was a change this time and it only offered me "Manual installation". This is different than previous installations where it gave me the three choices of dual boot, install over previous data or the Advanced installation choice.
The drives it showed me were what I expected. My M2 (my intended target) showed the three partitions I mentioned earlier:

nvme0n1p1 VFAT 104.86MB Windows Boot Manager
nvme0n1p2 16.78MB
nvme0n1p3 NTFS 1.02TB

In the "Device for boot loader installation", I chose nvme0n1 (1.02TB). I have not encountered this setup before. In the numerous attempts I tried before I was also given the option to dual boot. This iteration of my attempts brings up a whole new set of variables. I tried to create a 150GB partition formatted in ext4 for Ubuntu, but it appeared that this course of action turned the remaining 874GB into free space which I assume means it  overwrites my Windows OS. I wasn't expecting this turn of events.

I gave up. I bought another M2 Drive, took out the old one (which held my Windows OS), and put in a new, clean, 1TB M2. I installed 24.04 and the process went flawlessly. I am entering this post on my new Ubuntu desktop. I'm guessing a flaw developed in the partitions of my old M2/C: after a bunch of attempted installs, a couple of clean re-installs of windows, and then a few more attempted dual-boot installs of 24.04.
I'm moving on now. My plan is (and always has been) to see if I can live on Ubuntu alone. The only things I really love Windows for, is my Total War: Rome 2 gaming and my use of Microsoft OneNote. Other than that I have all the games, apps, VPNs, etc in Ubuntu.
